# Insert data from two table into another

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to generate and insert data from two tables in new one. 
I should take all data from **M** table where Type is `1` and all **C** data where type is also `1` and add it as shown in result

**Sample of data:**

M table:

```
+----+------+------+
| Id | Name | Type |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | M1   | 1    |
+----+------+------+
| 2  | M2   | 1    |
+----+------+------+
| 3  | M3   | 1    |
+----+------+------+
| 4  | M4   | 2    |
+----+------+------+
```

C table:

```
+----+------+------+
| Id | Name | Type |
+----+------+------+
| 1  | C1   | 1    |
+----+------+------+
| 2  | C2   | 1    |
+----+------+------+
| 3  | C3   | 2    |
+----+------+------+
| 4  | C4   | 2    |
+----+------+------+
```

Result:

```
+----+---+---+
| Id | C | M |
+----+---+---+
| 1  | 1 | 1 |
+----+---+---+
| 2  | 1 | 2 |
+----+---+---+
| 3  | 1 | 3 |
+----+---+---+
| 4  | 2 | 1 |
+----+---+---+
| 5  | 2 | 2 |
+----+---+---+
| 6  | 2 | 3 |
+----+---+---+
```

Comment: Take a look at SQL joins. There's no point in generating a new table. Use the SQL principles of store it once and retrieve as necessary.

Comment: I agree, but the data is for other purpose. And it has to be stored in new table for history records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select any variant of

```
    INSERT INTO c (c, m)
    SELECT c.id, m.id
    FROM c, m
    WHERE c.type = 1
      AND m.type = 1
```

```
    INSERT INTO c (c, m)
    SELECT c.id, m.id
    FROM c
    JOIN m ON m.type = 1
    WHERE c.type = 1
```

```
    INSERT INTO c (c, m)
    SELECT c.id, m.id
    FROM c
    JOIN m ON c.type = 1
    WHERE m.type = 1
```

```
    INSERT INTO c (c, m)
    SELECT c.id, m.id
    FROM c
    JOIN m ON m.type = 1
          AND c.type = 1
```

```
    INSERT INTO c (c, m)
    SELECT c.id, m.id
    FROM c
    JOIN m /* ON 1 = 1 */
    WHERE c.type = 1
      AND m.type = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this also works in PostgreSQL (since you added the tag) but the following is the MySQL way of doing it.

This looks to me like a merge operation on the two tables after replacing a string. Since it involves removing the prefixes "C" and "M" we can use the SQL `REPLACE([Column], [Needle], [Replacement])` method.

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(`C`.`Name`, 'C', '') AS C
FROM C
WHERE `C`.`Type` = 1
```

However, there is no merge operation in SQL, so we cannot use that approach. This would leave us to resort to using JOIN. Since this is a simple merge which no key matching is needed, we can simply add a dummy key to the table.

```
SELECT
    REPLACE(`C`.`Name`, 'C', '') AS C,
    'dummy' AS `tkey`
FROM C
WHERE `C`.`Type` = 1
```

We do that on Table `M` as well.

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(`M`.`Name`, 'M', '') AS M,
    'dummy' AS `tkey`
FROM M 
WHERE `M`.`Type` = 1
```

Since these are derived tables, we have to give them an alias.

```
(
    SELECT
        REPLACE(`C`.`Name`, 'C', '') AS C,
        'dummy' AS `tkey`
    FROM C
    WHERE `C`.`Type` = 1
) AS NewC
```

```
(
    SELECT 
    REPLACE(`M`.`Name`, 'M', '') AS M,
    'dummy' AS `tkey`
    FROM M 
    WHERE `M`.`Type` = 1
) AS NewM
```

By performing a LEFT JOIN on the two tables, you get the `C` and `M` columns as desired.

```
SELECT 
    NewC.`C`,
    NewM.`M`
FROM (
    SELECT
        REPLACE(`C`.`Name`, 'C', '') AS C,
        'dummy' AS `tkey`
    FROM C
    WHERE `C`.`Type` = 1
) AS NewC
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        REPLACE(`M`.`Name`, 'M', '') AS M,
        'dummy' AS `tkey`
        FROM M 
        WHERE `M`.`Type` = 1
    ) AS NewM
ON `NewM`.`tkey` = `NewC`.`tkey`
ORDER BY `NewC`.`C` ASC, `NewM`.`M` ASC
```

And implementing the autoincrement column from Source #3, we first wrap the above query into a subquery (if you would like to keep the order as in your demo):

```
(SELECT 
    NewC.`C`,
    NewM.`M`
FROM (
    SELECT
        REPLACE(`C`.`Name`, 'C', '') AS C,
        'dummy' AS `tkey`
    FROM C
    WHERE `C`.`Type` = 1
) AS NewC
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        REPLACE(`M`.`Name`, 'M', '') AS M,
        'dummy' AS `tkey`
        FROM M 
        WHERE `M`.`Type` = 1
    ) AS NewM
ON `NewM`.`tkey` = `NewC`.`tkey`
ORDER BY `NewC`.`C` ASC, `NewM`.`M` ASC) AS final
```

And we use a CROSS JOIN on a variable which would increment by 1:

```
SELECT
    (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS id,
    final.C,
    final.M
FROM
    (SELECT 
        NewC.`C`,
        NewM.`M`
    FROM (
        SELECT
            REPLACE(`C`.`Name`, 'C', '') AS C,
            'dummy' AS `tkey`
        FROM C
        WHERE `C`.`Type` = 1
    ) AS NewC
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        REPLACE(`M`.`Name`, 'M', '') AS M,
        'dummy' AS `tkey`
        FROM M 
        WHERE `M`.`Type` = 1
    ) AS NewM
ON `NewM`.`tkey` = `NewC`.`tkey`
ORDER BY `NewC`.`C` ASC, `NewM`.`M` ASC) AS final
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
```

And we are done.

Sources:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663074/is-merge-statement-available-in-mysql
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930514/mysql-auto-increment-temporary-column-in-select-statement

Comment: *it involves removing the prefixes "C" and "M* OP uses `M.Id` and `C.Id`, it seems, not `Name` fields... *there is no merge operation in SQL* ??? it exists. *By performing a LEFT JOIN on the two tables* Why LEFT? Inner is enough. *And implementing the autoincrement column* Postgre knows about window functions.